# The development server returned response error code: 500 {react Native}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was setting up the navigations in my App.Js while encountered this error and I am completely clueless that how to solve this issue. Can someone help me?

[image: Home.JS]

[image: Error]

And just pasting the code of App.Js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import Registeration from "../screens/Registeration";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View >
            <Home />
            <Button
                    title="Go to Login"
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
function RegisterationScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View >
            <Registeration />
            <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
            <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        </View>
    );
}
function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View >
            <Login />
            <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
            <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={{ title: 'Home' }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Registeration"
                    component={RegisterationScreen}
                    options={{ title: 'Registeration' }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Login"
                    component={LoginScreen}
                    options={{ title: 'Login' }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you read the error? `Unable to resolve module ../screens/Home from  C:\...`